# Regex split java

Tags: java, regex, split, bufferedreader

Good fellows, could you help me find a regex with split to separate the attributes of a string (txt file), the string is the following line:

```
{'title': 'The signal', 'description': 'Una crisis nerviosa. Un ataque de pánico en pleno sermón, 'img': '9b9f6e903588a16bf90eb86ff7b079ba.jpg', 'Format': 'physic book', 'Author': 'Young, wm. paul - jersak, bradley', 'Editorial': 'Diana', 'Year': '2021', 'Idiom': 'Español', 'Isbn': '9789584293817', 'Isbn13': '9789584293817'}{'titulo': 'Quemar el Miedo', 'descripcion': 'Este es el manifiesto escrito por el Colectivo LASTESIS. , 'img': 'f56123687ddc0167a0f4186612293435.jpg', 'Formato': 'Libro físico', 'Autor': '', 'Año': '2021', 'Idioma': 'Español', 'Isbn': '9789584293626', 'Isbn13': '9789584293626'}
```

I need to get the values ​​of each element to be able to rebuild the object

```java
public static boolean cargarlibros(){    
  File f = new File(FILENAME);
  FileReader reader;
  try {
    reader = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader buffr = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String registro; 
    while((registro = buffr.readLine()) != null){
      String[] datos = registro.split("\\{\\}");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datos));                              
    }
    buffr.close();
    reader.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    return false;
  }        
  return true;
}
```

Comment: looks like JSON text with missing quote after `sermón`, parse it with a JSON library will be easier

Comment: why not split the string on the comma?

Comment: What is this data supposed to be? Because while it _looks_ like JSON, it very much isn't: single-quoting is not spec-compliant. Only double-quotes are used in JSON.

Comment: I'd look for a specialised parser for this format, rather than trying to use regular expressions.  Is there any way you can use JSON instead of this variant?  That will give you more options.

Comment: It is a plain text file with that structure, it is a single line with all the data and each one is separated with {book1} {book2} {book3} ...

Comment: the other option was to use the split with the vertical bar "|", but in the flat file there was data in null and the object could not be reconstructed

Comment: OK, how about if you replace every `'` with a `"` and then give it to a JSON parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add and change quotes in order to convert your data to JSON, but that may be not trivial especially if the string contains apostrophes, and I think parsing it as is is easier. Your `split` attempt didn't work because the pattern `"\\{\\}"` would only split at `{}`, which isn't there. You could replace

```
      String[] datos = registro.split("\\{\\}");
```

with

```
      String[] datos = registro.replaceFirst("^\\{", "").split("}\\{|}$");
      for (var dato: datos)
      {
        String[] elems = dato.replaceFirst("^'", "").split("'?[:,] '|'$");
        Map<String, String> book = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < elems.length; ) book.put(elems[i++], elems[i++]);
        …
      }
```

As you didn't say into what data structure you want *to get the values ​​of each element*, I chose a `Map`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is the regex I needed, I am going to rebuild the object and then I have a method where I insert them in an Arraylist, thanks